# WebApi2 Routing with Get Request does not work

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Hi I'm making a simple program that you can search for the user, register the user, and get all the user that are registered.

I want to be able to search for my users using

> /api/user/search?name=...&email= B

But this is not working. I get an error that is:

> {
>     "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:63881/api/user/search'.",
>     "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'User' that matches the request."
>   }

I have code that looks like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
        // Check if the user is in the database 
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Return All");
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(UserForm form) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false) {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
        if (form == null) {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please enter data");
        }
        // Register the person
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Register");
    }

    [Route("search/{name}/{email}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage SearchGet(string name, string email) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Found");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you hit /api/user/search/bob/jim

Comment: Yes that works but I wanted it to also work with passing /api/user/search?name=...&email= B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another route attribute to the SearchGet method should work:

```
[Route("search") ] 
[Route("search/{name}/{email}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage SearchGet(string name, string email) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Found");
    }
```

It will map the request based on the querystring parameter count and name or each querystring parameter.

Comment: Bizarre. That's working fine for me. Go to `/Help` in your app in the browser. Do you see a list of APIs? Is your one listed in here? Can you send me the exact request you're sending in to search? I'm using `/api/user/search?name=Bob&email=b@b.com` and getting a valid response.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that I passed the same parameters through as in your example. "..." for name and " B" for email. It still worked.